# How to convert "10_000_00" string class to 10_000_00 Integer class

Tags: ruby

How can I convert the following "integer" strings into there underscored Integer class counter parts?

Examples:

"10_000_00" => 10_000_00

"500_000_00" => 500_000_00

etc. etc

Comment: Underscores in numeric literals are purely syntactic.

Comment: There are no "underscored integers". An integer is a numeric value, represented internally as a binary number. An integer [_literal_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming)) can have underscores, but `10_000_00` and `1000000` and `1_0_0_0_0_0_0` are all understood to be the same number, and represented equivalently during the execution. If you want to preserve a particular _representation_ of an integer, like `10_000_00`, `0xf4240` or `0b1111_0100_0010_0100_0000`, that's what strings are for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`String#to_i`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/String.html#method-i-to_i) translates the string representation of a number to an integer:

```
"10_000_00".to_i
#=> 1000000

"500_000_00".to_i
#=> 50000000
```

Note that underscores in integers are only syntactic sugar to make the more readable in source code, but there is nothing special about those integers

```
10_000_00 == 1000000 
#=> true
```